# PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose

the issue is that I'm using docker with springboot 3.2.2 which means I have compose.yaml file under the project directory.

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    restart: always
    environment:
      - 'POSTGRES_DB=example'
      - 'POSTGRES_USER=postgres'
      - 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin'
    volumes:
      - './db/create_db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create_db.sql'
      - './db/create_db_tables.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/20-create_db_tables.sql'
      - './db/init_profiles.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/50-create_profiles.sql'
      - './db/init_users.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/60-init_users.sql'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
```

The db directory is the root folder of the project.

When I update the create_db_tables script to add columns, it wasn't taken into consideration.

Then I noticed the following log in the docker desktop

```
2024-02-05 11:30:02 PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
```

Please note i'm starting the springboot application directly under Eclipse (run as springboot application).

Any help is appreciated.

I have tried to delete the image directly under docker desktop but it doesn't seem the work.
I was expecting the image to be recreated but it seems to not take my new sql files into consideration.